# I can't install mediawiki on the google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, mediawiki

I installed everything. Followed the instructions and then once I finished I put LocalSettings.php on the same folder as index.php. That is site/wiki/ Yet it still says that LocalSettings.php is missing. I typed the address LocalSettings.php and it gives me a 404. Its almost as if LocalSettings.php is being blocked. How do I fix this?

Comment: Make sure that space in `LocalSettings. php` isn't there, too. It should be `LocalSettings.php`.

Comment: I saved it as LocalSettings.php I just wrote it like that because this site thought I was trying to type code for some odd reason.

Comment: Wrong file permissions, presumably?

Answer (score 1):

https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:LocalSettings.php

> The `LocalSettings.php` file is not a wiki page and you cannot access it with your web browser.